# How to calculate visits by month if customers has assigned days of visits

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, unpivot

i have this table

```
customer sunday monday tuesday wedesneday thursday friday saturday
1        0      0       1       1          1       0       0
2        0      1       0       0          0       0       1
3        0      0       1       0          1       0       1
4        0      0       1       1          0       1       0
5        0      1       0       0          1       1       1
6        0      0       1       0          1       1       0
7        0      1       0       1          1       0       1
8        0      0       0       0          1       1       0
9        0      1       1       1          0       0       1
```

now i have next parameter> year and months january, february, march(or any user chooses)
**how scheduled visits are going to have by month?**

Note: for every month no precisely start with sunday or finish with saturday, and monts
doesn't have the same quantities days.

I believe i could get the first day and last day for every month choosed by user

with a loop and a select using datepart > datepart(weekday,'1/'+(some month)+'\'+year_choosed_by_user)

I believe i could get something as it

```
month, startday, lastday, days
1        0         2       31
2        3         3       29
3        4         6       30
```

where 0=sunday and 6=saturday, could it help? i'll get this #tmptable using datepart

Comment: you have information loses. What year is first line?

Comment: what more do you need? @bluefeet

Comment: @FlorinGhita, customers has the same scheduled visits every year

Comment: ok, I think I understand the question now. But I'm not good on Sql Server, sorry.

Comment: @angel even with your explanation in the comments i still don't see how this is possible given the data you've provided. there's no way to discern the month from anything in the question as you've posed it. could you please post what your desired results will look like?

Comment: The question is quite unclear, I would suggest to reformulate it. Also, the sample table is not normalised, which makes querying it with SQL a very hard task.

Comment: datepart could help @swasheck

Comment: @angel sure it could ... if you had a date anywhere in your data at all.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @swasheck i believe i need is start day, finish day, and how many days has every month, wouldn't it be enough?

Comment: @angel What is the result that you want from a query? Can you edit your post and provide desired result?

Comment: How can you tell the month and the year of any given day in your table? at least the start day.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal could you see, last thing i have added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not exactly clear what you are trying to do but the solution below, creates a list of dates, `UNPIVOT`s your existing data and then gets a count of how many appointments for each month:

```
;with dates (datevalue) as
(
  select cast('2012-10-01' as datetime)
  union all
  select dateadd(d, 1, datevalue)
  from dates
  where dateadd(d, 1, datevalue) <= cast('2012-12-01' as datetime)
) 
select count(*) TotalAppts, datename(month, d.datevalue) [Month]
from dates d
inner join 
(
  select client, value, col
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, 
                Thursday, Friday, Saturday)
  ) unpiv
) src
  on datename(dw, d.datevalue) = col
where value = 1
group by datename(month, d.datevalue)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee2c7/12)

Result:

```
| TOTALAPPTS |    MONTH |
-------------------------
|          5 | December |
|        122 | November |
|        125 |  October |
```

Comment: You are not filtering on `value`. Only `1` days should be counted. Otherwise fine!

Comment: good answer! i was working up the way to create the dates which is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b048/4). @angel, combine the two and you should be set

Comment: @angel: If you need also to split the figures by customers, just add the `client` column (or `customer` or whatever the actual equivalent is) both to the `group by` and to the main `select`.

Comment: Thanks, i haven't never seen a pivot/unpivot but the last result is the right result.

Answer (score 0):

You might do well to employ some sort of bitmask. For example, assign the days of the week a value according to binary numbers:

```
Sunday     1
Monday     2
Tuesday    4
Wednesday  8
Thursday  16
Friday    32
Saturday  64
```

And the same for months of the year:

```
January       1
February      2
March         4
April         8
May          16
June         32
July         64
August      128
September   256
October     512
November   1024
December   2048
```

In your table structure, you need only three columns as follows:

```
customer_id (INT)  days (INT)   months (INT)
1                  28           0
2                  66           0
3                  84           0
```

Customer 1 visits on Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday. These values equal 28 as shown in the above example. For any given combination of days of week, the resulting number is unique due to binary addition. If you deconstruct the integer 28, it has the binary form:

```
00011100
```

If you consider only the last 7 places, the `1` values correspond to Tues, Wed, Thurs just like your multiple columns.

So how does this help? You can use [bitwise operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) to construct queries.

If you need to determine, for example, what customers visit on Monday, you would need to `OR` the days column with its value, 2.

For customers that visit in May and June, you would use the value 48.

This suggestion may be useful for you in decreasing the number of columns and simplifying queries, but I'm not 100% sure what you're asking.